# Get Null when Binding List of Object to Controller MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am having trouble binding a model that contains list of objects for Editing method. This is the list of `Factory` which includes list of another object (`FactoryHotline`).

There is no problem when I get pass data from Controller to View. But when I try to  send data from View back to Controller, some model's properties always null.

The Model is:

```
public class Factory 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<FactoryHotline> FactoryHotlineList { get; set; }
}

public class FactoryHotline 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid FactoryId { get; set; }

        public string Caption { get; set; }

        public string Hotline { get; set; }
    }
```

This is View:

```
@model List<WebDataLayer.Models.Factory>

<form action="/Factories/Edit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <table id="factoriesTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th class="Hotline1" >Hotline 1</th>
                    <th class="Hotline2" >Hotline 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Id)
                     <tr>
                         <td>@Model[i].Name</td>

                        @for (int h = 0; h < Model[i].FactoryHotlineList.Count; h++)
                        {
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <b>Caption: </b>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].FactoryHotlineList[h].Caption, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ShortInput", id = "captionInput", maxlength = "39" } })
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <b>Hotline:</b>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].FactoryHotlineList[h].Hotline, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ShortInput", id = "hotlineInput", maxlength = "15" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].FactoryHotlineList[h].Hotline)
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
</form>
```

In my controller the method for Edit is:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit (List<Factory> factories)
        {
        }
```

Only Id has value, the other(Caption, Hotline) are always null in `List<Factory> factories`

This is how I am passing Data from Controller to View

```
// GET: Edit
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            var factories = _factoryService.All().OrderBy(p => p.Name);
            var list = factories.ToList();
            return View("Edit", list);
        }
```

I works fine using Entity Framework.

Comment: How are you passing data to your view?

Comment: just updated my code, it works when passing Data from Controller to View @Sakuto

Answer (score -1):

That is because you have used `HiddenFor` to keep id as hidden field. To have the value in postback, it should be a part of input element(input,select,checkbox,textarea,etc) or as hidden field.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Name)
```

I would suggest using a [viewmodel along with automapper](https://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/view-model-pattern-and-automapper-in-asp-net-mvc-applications) in this case.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. The reason I have to use '@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Id)' is because I want to pass the value of Id to Controller while there is nothing to do with Id field in View. And in this case, in Controller, Id has value. The other like: Caption, Hotline are null.

Comment: That's correct. Have them as hidden in for loop and it would exist in postback.

Comment: So I'm right to use HiddenFor for Id. And there is no reason to use input element(input,select,checkbox,textarea,etc) for ID

Comment: I want to get value from @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].FactoryHotlineList[h].Caption and @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].FactoryHotlineList[h].Hotline, not Name

Comment: @vyclarks : you would get them in postback controller using `factories[indexhere].FactoryHotlineList[hotlinindex].Caption ` and `factories[indexhere].FactoryHotlineList[hotlinindex].Hotline`

Comment: no, the issue is it is already null when it is just passed from View. Of course I know how to get it in Controller but It has to be not null first.  `public ActionResult Edit (List<Factory> factories)
        {
        }` Did the debug then I saw Caption and Hotline in List<Factory> factories are null

Comment: @vyclarks: Can you try removing ID attribute for caption and hotline. That's causing duplicate ids on page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192414/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-vyclarks).